# Disable notice errors in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have some old code that I am migrating from laravel 4 to laravel 6. The notice errors were suppressed in the old code.

There are a lot of undefined index issues in the old code and I would change it by adding some array_key_exists() or isset but for now I need to move the code without much code change.

The below code was added in the old code in global.php.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

I want to disable the same, added the same line in config/app.php in Laravel 6 and I can't seem to disable it. Appreciate any help

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);  [more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Where should I add it in the Laravel 6 code?

Comment: AppServiceProvider method boot

Comment: [see link](https://pastebin.com/rjep5Kwc)

Comment: This worked thanks

Answer (score 4):

Need to add error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE); to boot method

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    }
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```